# Synonym for "fraction" or single word for "too small percentage"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I'd like to use another word instead of "fraction" that emphasise smallness. What can I say in this sentence:

> Among the 20,000 members who were invited to the program, only 20 of
>   them participated which is a **fraction** of the invited members.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47366/discussion-on-question-by-mfr-synonym-for-fraction-or-single-word-for-too-sma).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, *fraction* is an appropriate word choice.

From Dictionary.com:

> [*fraction*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/fraction): a very small
> part or segment of anything; minute portion

The problem, if there is one, is that *fraction* also means one number divided by another, with no connotation of largeness or smallness.

One way to address that problem, if there is one, would be to use *small or tiny  fraction*, or perhaps better, *small or tiny percentage*.

> Among the 20,000 members who were invited to the program, only 20 of
> them participated, which is a *small fraction* (0.001) of the invited
> members.
>
> Among the 20,000 members who were invited to the program, only 20 of
> them participated, which is a *small percentage* (0.1%) of the invited
> members.

Either way, both *fraction* and *percentage* capture that you want to make a relative comparison, i.e., a comparison of the number of actual attendees to the number of potential attendees based on the number of invitations sent out. Either way though, it would appear that for clarity's sake, both would warrant a subjective adjective such as *small* or *tiny*.

Answer (score 1):

As explained by Richard, the word "fraction" by itself is ambiguous and doesn't necessarily communicate that the number of members was **too** small.

I recommend using the word [insignificant](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/insignificant).

> > adjective: small or unimportant: not significant

as in

> > Among the 20,000 members who were invited to the program, only 20 of them participated which is an **insignificant portion** of the invited members.